# Returning a global variable from a method

Tags: javascript, methods, scope

I want to create a variable that is accessed globally inside a method.  (I think I'm using the right terminology).

Take for instance, jQuery's `.hover()`.  Inside of it, I'm trying to access a class name on the fly and store that for later manipulation within other methods and functions outside the scope of the original `.hover()`

```
$('elem').hover(function() {
    var classname = $(this)something;
    return classname;
});

console.log(classname);
```

I'm trying to use this globally since this affects more methods than just this one.

I'm sure there's a completely different programming method I should be using to get this done, but returning values outside of a method seems like the only process available to my small knowledge base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of choices:

1. Use a scoping function around your code, and use local variables inside that scoping function. All functions *within* the scoping function have access to those variables:

   ```
   (function() {
       var classname = "";

       $('elem').hover(function() {
           classname = this.className;
       });

       $('some other elem').on('some-other-event', function() {
           console.log(classname);
       });
   })();
   ```

   Note how the second event handler has access to the same variable that the `hover` handler has access to. In both cases, they have an *enduring reference to the variable*, not a *copy* of the variable. More: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).
2. Use a global variable, which is basically just a special case of the above.

I recommend #1. Here's a complete example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ikohABi/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ikohABi/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Simple Closure</title>
  <style>
    .a, .b, .c {
      width: 60px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hover over these:</p>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var prevClassHovered = "";
      var lastClassHovered = "";

      // Remember the last hovered thing
      $(".a, .b, .c").hover(function() {
        lastClassHovered = this.className;
      });

      // Output the last one every ~500 ms, if it's
      // changed. Here the event in question is a
      // timer event, but of course it can be anything.
      setInterval(function() {
        if (prevClassHovered !== lastClassHovered) {
          prevClassHovered = lastClassHovered;
          display(lastClassHovered);
        }
      }, 500);

      function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer.  This really helps.  I don't understand why there's a second `()` at the end. What is the purpose of that?  Also, this is the second time I've seen msg passed to a function.  Is this special, or can I use any variable?

Comment: @ShawnStrickland: The `()` near the end *call* the anonymous function. Without them, it's just a function expression defining a function that nothing would ever call, and so the code in the function would never be run. E.g., `(function() { console.log("You never see this"); })`.

Comment: Is there any danger in using a global variable, particularly defining something without the `var` keyword, saving some lines in the process?

Comment: @ShawnStrickland: In browsers, the global JS environment is incredibly crowded. Every element with an `id` is dropped in it, some browsers do `name`s too, there are a bunch of predefined globals... I advocate avoiding globals entirely. Re "saving lines" by not using `var`: You don't save any lines. You save 1-4 chars (4 for `var ` for the first and 1 for each `,` for add'l ones). If you want to save chars, use a minifier/compressor. The [*Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://bit.ly/1eDRyfq) is exactly that, I recommend using strict mode to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do something like

```
var classname;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('elem').hover(function () {
        classname = $(this) something;
        console.log(classname);
    });
    $('elem').click(function () {
        console.log(classname);
    })
});



console.log(classname);
```

now you can use it everywhere

Comment: When I tried this, the second function - the click function - doesn't seem to register, and the last call to log to the console returns undefined.

Comment: I did get it working, but console.log(classname); never wanted to work.  I can invoke the classname variable in the console but not have it invoke itself.  Is it because we're tying this to a hover state only?  And it's firing itself off immediately before the hover is initiated?

Answer (score 1):

You can define global variables by either defining the variable outside the function, or by defining the variable via `window.varName = 'value'`. For example:

```
$('elem').hover(function() {
    window.classname = $(this)something;
    return classname;
});
```

Then the variable classname will be globally defined, and you can call it by simply treating it as any other variable. You don't need to prepend the `window.` every time you call it.

Alternatively, like nzn said, you can define the variable outside the function, and then assign a new value without prepending `var` to it. For example:

```
var classname;
$('elem').hover(function() {
    classname = $(this)something;
    return classname;
});
```

That will do the exact same thing as the `window.` method, but in this case you first need to define the variable outside the function, while you don't need to do that with `window.classname`. Do keep in mind though that you should watch out with global variables. Before calling the global value you should be 100% sure the variable is defined when you call it. If you are not exactly sure about if it's defined, then the method of defining the variable outside the function is definitely better.

Comment: That's a nice shortcut!  I appreciate the elaboration.